# Make the root partition backup bootable?

Tags: boot, backup

I have backed-up my `/` partition on a external HDD. I want to boot this since I dont want to waste time re-installing all the packages that are in here on other system. Is there any way achieve this?

Comment: I think making chroot jail is the only solution to this...

Comment: It depends on how you backed up. I suggest you edit the question and add more information.